# Naming threads when using Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

I use multitasking a lot and I am working on adding Reactive Extensions into my set of tools.  However I prefer to name threads so that I can better understand what threads are running when I break etc.  In general it is just better.  However I haven't found a good way to name threads when I am using reactive extensions with SubscribeOn and ObserveOn etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the `NewThreadScheduler` alot, you can make a subclass of it that customizes the `Thread` it creates and then use your custom scheduler when using `ObserveOn` or `SubscribeOn`...

```
// created threads will have names prefixed with "bob"
someObservable.ObserveOn(new CustomNewThreadScheduler("bob"))...
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've done in the past, although I swapped back over to the pool when I switched to Release.

Answer (score 1):

When using Rx, most of the "threads" fall into three camps:

1. The target of `SubscribeOn` or `ObserveOn`, which will be based on the framework's specified `SynchronizationContext`.  This is going to typically be the "main UI" thread if you're using a user interface, so naming the main thread will provide you the proper name.
2. ThreadPool threads, which really cannot (or at least typically should not) be named, as they don't have a specific lifecycle which appears and goes away.  If an event is raised on a ThreadPool thread, and being observed, there is no good way to "name" these threads.
3. A thread you've created yourself, which could easily be named if you so choose.

Since 2/3 of the options allow you to provide names, you could always name those threads, then assume any unnamed thread watched during debugging is a ThreadPool managed thread.